# Variable Python a otro programa

Tags: python, variables

Hola a todo el mundo,

Estoy haciendo un bucle en **programa1.py** en el que en cada vuelta debe llamar a **programa2.py**

```
import subprocess

x = 1
total = 10

while x <= total:
    process1 = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'programa2.py'])
    x += 1
```

El caso es que quiero ejecutar **programa2.py** y que este me devuelva el valor de x con el valor que se actualiza en cada vuelta del bucle.

```
from programa1.py import x

print(x)
```

Esta fórmula no me funciona, pues **programa2.py** toma siempre el valor x = 1, alguien sabe cómo enviar a **programa2.py** el valor que quiero para x?

Muchísimas gracias

Comment: Si lo que quieres comunicar es un entero, puedes hacer en `programa2.py` un `sys.exit(x)`, y en `programa1.py`, tras crear el proceso, esperar a que termine con `process1.communicate()` y entonces tendrás su valor de salida (o sea, el valor de x) en `process1.returncode`.

Answer (score 3):

Cuando ejecutas `programa2.py` en el subproceso, éste **importa `programa1.py` y lo ejecuta desde cero**, por lo que **el valor de `x` será el que inicialmente tenga dicha variable global en el módulo**, no el que tiene en tu proceso padre actual. Son dos procesos completamente distintos, con sus propias variables globales y estado en general.

Ten en cuenta que además haces algo bastante peligroso si no tienes la creación del subproceso bajo `if __name__ == "__main__"`. Veamos, `programa2` ejecuta `programa1` como subproceso, este a su vez importa a `programa1`, lo cual implica ejecutarlo, por lo que el subproceso a su vez llama a otro proceso `programa1`, y así sucesivamente....

Además, `subprocess.Popen` no es bloqueante por defecto, lanza el proceso y tu código continua ejecutándose sin esperar a que el subproceso termine (a no ser que se use `subprocess.Popen.wait()` o `subprocess.Popen.comunicate()`). Esto significa que puedes modificar `x` y llamar a otro subproceso hijo antes que que el anterior termine. No se si es esto lo que quieres, pero debes tenerlo en cuenta.

Si quieres que `programa2` haga algo distinto en función del valor de `x` en tu proceso actual, haz que `programa2` acepte `x` como argumento. Como ejemplo, `programa2` va a elevar al cuadrado el valor de x y eventualmente retornarlo:

```
# programa2.py
import sys

x = int(sys.argv[1])
print(x ** 2)
sys.exit(0)
```

- Usando `subproces.Popen`:

  ```
  # programa1.py
  import subprocess

  x = 1
  total = 10

  if __name__ == "__main__":
      for x_val in range(x, total + 1):
          process1 = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'programa2.py', str(x_val)],
                                      stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

          out = process1.communicate()[0]
          print(int(out))
  ```

  En este caso se espera que el subproceso termine mediante la llamada a `communicate`.
- Usando `subprocess.run` (espera a que el proceso termine, concurrencia pero no paralelismo)

  ```
  # programa1.py
  import subprocess

  x = 1
  total = 10

  if __name__ == "__main__":
      for x_val in range(x, total + 1):
          process1 = subprocess.run(['python', 'programa2.py', str(x_val)], capture_output=True)
          out = process1.stdout
          print(int(out))
  ```

Dado que ambos procesos son programas Python, hay formas de hacer esto sin recurrir a `subprocess`, incluso si quieres paralelismo (multiprocessing).